# which window object does getBackgroundPage() method really return?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, return-value, window-object

in the documentation, it says, getBackgroundPage()

> Returns the JavaScript 'window' object for the background page running
>   inside the current extension.

which window is it? is it the same window that we get with: "chrome.windows.getCurrent()".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you specify a background page in your `manifest.json`, the page is actually 'open' when your extension is running (go to `chrome://extensions` and look for extensions with a property `Inspect views: some_background_page.html`). Although you can't actually see the page, it does exist, and as the documentation states, running `getBackgroundPage()` will return that page's 'window' object, allowing you to perform all of the actions you could on a normal window (see [here](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/obj_window.asp) for a list of some of those properties/actions).

To answer your second question, you can read [here](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/windows.html#current-window) that the value of current window falls back to the last active window when being called from a background page. Here is a sample `background.js` that may help explain - it will show identical IDs for `getCurrent` and `getAllinWindow`, both of which will refer to the page from the active/visible page from which you called the extension - not the background page itself:

```
//  This gets all current window tabs
chrome.tabs.getAllInWindow(null, function(tabs){
  // This alerts the window ID when getCurrent is called from background.js
  chrome.windows.getCurrent(function(window){
    alert("Background ID: " + window.id);
    });

  // Now we loop through the tabs returned by getAllInWindow,
  // showing the window ID. The ID is identical to the one above,
  // meaning that getCurrent (when called from a background page)
  // returns the current active window - NOT the background page
  chrome.windows.get(tabs[0].windowId, function(window) {
    alert("Active Window: " + window.id);
  });
});
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: rocketdonkey could you expand your explanation to your second paragraph?

Comment: @burhan Sure, dropped in an example. Let me know if that helps.

Comment: thanks rocketdonkey. say, we have popup.js like this  
`backgd = chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage();  
......  
backgd.Clipboard.write(Text);`  
what does this script do then?

Comment: @burhan Hmm, it looks like it is intending to write to the clipboard, but I haven't ever seen a `Clipboard` property like that. The only way I know of (which doesn't say much :) ) to copy data to the clipboard is to use `document.execCommand('copy')` (see http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifest.html#permissions, by the `clipboardWrite` permission). Is that what you're trying to do?

Comment: i came across the above `popup.js` in an extension. as far as i see, too, it saves `Text` to the clipboard. i wonder which window returned with `getBackGroundPage` method and why it uses that window's clipboard `property` to write to.

Comment: @burhan It could be that there is some property specific to the background page that needs to be copied to the clipboard. However I can't say for sure :) Does the above explanation make sense in terms of the difference?